# CanCan, setting up a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have the following models:

```
Group (id)
Poll (id, group_id)
PollVote (id, poll_id)
```

I don't want to do deep nesting, meaning I don't want /group/:id/poll/:id/poll_vote/:id

I want to set it up so my routes:

```
/group/:id
/poll/:id
/poll/:id/poll_vote/:poll_vote_id
```

I have poll working, but I can't figure out how to get PollVote working... So far I have:

```
class PollVotesController < ApplicationController

  # Authorization w Devise & CanCan
  before_filter :authenticate_user! # Devise, signed in users only
  load_and_authorize_resource :poll # CanCan
  load_and_authorize_resource :poll_vote, :through => :poll

  # We need to pass along the wall
    def current_ability
        @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, @poll.group_id)
    end
```

Then in ability.rb

```
can [:manage], Poll do |poll|
    This returns TRUE is the user is a group member of the poll
end
```

What do I use in PollVotes, to have PollVotes check CanCan using Poll?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your User <-> Group association, so if `User has_and_belongs_to_many :groups` then:

```
can :manage, [ Poll ] { |poll| user.groups.include?(poll.group) }
```

Of course, you probably want to lock that down to only votes associated with the user.

Edit - here are examples for restricting access to creating and editing poll votes:

```
can :read, PollVote # not needed if you have e.g. can :read, :all
can :create, [ PollVote ] { |poll_vote| user.groups.include?(poll_vote.poll.group) }
can [ :edit, :destroy ], [ PollVote ] { |poll_vote| poll_vote.user_id == user.id }
```

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for this... What I'm confused about is in ability.rb do I also need a can :manage, PollVote?

Comment: Also, how would I lock it down to only votes associated with the user? Thanks so much, hard finding docs on this nesting stuff for CanCan

Comment: @AnApprentice: I've added more examples to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but I'm still a little confused. Do I need to add PollVote to my ability.rb if I use load_and_authorize_resource :poll_vote, :through => :poll in the controller? Shoulnd't Just having Poll in ability.rb take care of it? And just need PollVote if I want to restrict access?